# What does a breathtaking discovery mean?

Tags: humankind

On humankind you may find "Breathtaking" territories etc.

What impact do these Breathtaking Territories have on your cities or outposts? I can't see any difference in outpost output or outpost cost?

This is the notification for the discovery.

[image: Discovery Notification]

This is where the territory is located on my map

[image: Territory Location]

These are the yields of the territory
[image: Territory Yields]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get some fame for being the first to discover a [landmark](https://humankind.fandom.com/wiki/Landmark). And while [natural wonders](https://humankind.fandom.com/wiki/Natural_Wonder) will give bonuses to an outpost/city if you claim the region containing it (if you hover over the wonder, you'll see a pop up), landmarks do not.

> Landmarks are terrain features that are named in Humankind, with no
> special effects on the tile yields. They are discovered through
> exploration and revealing the map, and have five different types:
> Lake, Mountain, River, Forest, Desert.
>
> Once a landmark is fully revealed, the Empire that fully explored it
> will become the "discoverer" of the landmark and receive a bit Fame.